# When reading a Json file it would not understand HTML content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I was expecting my HTML page to display the json content in the HTML element specified for example in this case Display data in red colour However it would just not do it and display it as it is ?. I am using D3 data driven document to display json data in the form of a tree(parent-child relationship). Is it possible of what i am trying ?

IMAGE:

[image]

Json file:

```
{
   "name":"Business Direction IM RM",
   "children":[
      {
         "name":" <font color=\"red\">Sean /Bur/XYZ<\/font> ",
         "children":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "name":" <font color=\"red\">Vijay /Fish/XYZ<\/font> ",
         "children":[

         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 11px sans-serif;
  font-weight:900;
  font-size:12px;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 40, right: 220, bottom: 20, left: 220},
    width = 500 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 1750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("flare.json", function(error, flare) {
  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

</script>
```

Solution:

```
//Edited Code     
  nodeEnter.append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";})
  .attr('fill', function(d) { return d.name.color; })
  .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
```

Comment: I don't think SVG text nodes render HTML. You are better off storing the color as a property and then use CSS or SVG styling.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how much data you're working with, and whether you are able to go back through it all and clean it up manually. The cleanest solution would be as Justin Niessner mentioned, to remove the html markup from the json file, and add a `color` property to each entry:

```
{
   "name":"Business Direction IM RM",
   "children":[
      {
         "name": "Sean /Bur/XYZ",
         "color": "red",
         "children":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "name": "Vijay /Fish/XYZ",
         "color": "red",
         "children":[

         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

If you aren't able to edit the data directly, or there is too much of it to edit manually, you could use regular expressions to get the parts of the string that you want to use.

```
var name_regexp = /.*?\<.*?\>(.*?)\<.*?\>/;
var color_regexp = /.*?color\=\"(.*?)\".*/;
```

then when you draw your `text` element you would write:

```
nodeEnter.append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
  })
  // USE THE REGEXPs HERE
  .attr('fill', function(d) {
      return d.name.replace(color_regexp, '$1');
  })
  .text(function(d) {
      return d.name.replace(name_regexp, '$1');
  })
  .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8G6w4/) to see what those regular expressions are doing.

Comment: Great! your solution did work for my existing json object using the regular expression part. However i did manage to add the color property to my json object but when i run it now it does not display any names at all ? I have pasted the edited code in my question can you please check and point me what is missing ?

Comment: I think you are missing a comma too after the color property example: "color":"red",

Comment: Yep I was missing a couple commas. As for your solution above, you are not setting any text for your text node. Add the line `.text(function(d){ return d.name; })`. Also, the line for color should be `.attr('fill', function(d) { return d.color; })` rather than `d.name.color`

Answer (score 0):

All of your javaScript code creates SVG elements, not HTML. D3 will simply render everything you give the `<text>` block as text rather than render it as HTML somehow and then convert to SVG.

I would suggest simply adding a `color` property to your JSON object. You could then change your rendering code to:

```
nodeEnter.append('text')
    .attr('fill', function(d) { return d.color; })
    // the rest of your rendering
```

Comment: @Justine are you saying to add a color property in the external Json file ? and then add .attr('fill', function(d) { return d.color; }) to the text as you mentioned above ? can you please elaborate or give an example ?